# Conditional style css

Tags: html, css

Is there a way in which I can condense my divider CSS into a single entry rather than two separate ones? Read my comments in my psuedo code for more clarification. I'd like to have the ability to write my classes like this...

```
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="divider vertical"></div>
```

instead of this

```
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="divider-vertical"></div>
```

I have to now define my divider color in other css entries rather than just one time.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/7frUZq9Ekw?file=css

```
/* Divider */
.divider{
  @apply flex items-center h-px my-4 bg-red-500;
}

.divider-vertical {
  @apply flex self-stretch w-px my-4 bg-blue-500;
}
```

psuedo style

```
.divider {
   /* defaults always included */
   @apply flex bg-red-500;

   /* conditional...if div does not contain `vertical` class then do */
   @apply items-center h-px my-4;

   /* else if it does contain `vertical` then use this */
   @apply self-stretch w-px mx-4
}
```

Comment: You either need to investigate [BEM](http://getbem.com/), or use Tailwind as intended and apply the classes you need, instead of `.divider` vs `.divider-vertical`. Are you using PostCSS?

Comment: All you have to do is replace the `-` character in css with a `.` character and it will work like the first example. And you only need to put the changes in the following blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how you can combine multiple classes in css using the `.` character to give them different results.

```css
.a { color: red; }
.b { color: green; }
.c { color: blue; }
.d { color: cyan; }

.b.c { color: yellow; }
.a.d { color: purple; }
.c.d { color: orange; }
```

```html
<div class='a'>This is a</div>
<div class='b'>This is b</div>
<div class='c'>This is c</div>
<div class='d'>This is d</div>
<br>
<div class='a b'>This is a and b </div>
<div class='a c'>This is a and c</div>
<div class='b c'>This is b and c</div>
<div class='a d'>This is a and d</div>
<div class='c d'>This is c and d</div>
```